# Dlookup dependant on Label/Textbox

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to figure out how I can make my Dlookup function to look as its associated label and the value of that label.

My example is:

```
=DLookup("[OfficeOf]","tblLocationMSTR","[LocationCode]=LABEL CONTENT HERE")
```

And on top of that, I need to add a Mid() command for something like this:

```
=DLookup("[OfficeOf]","tblLocationMSTR","[LocationCode]=Mid("LABEL CONTENT HERE")")
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  If you tell us your intent we may be able to get you there another way.

Comment: I am creating a map with multiple rooms and I want the textbox fields to look at the Label's caption information to deduce the text that gets put into the box. Such as: Label1's caption is "RM 01-01-01". So in the textbox it says "George". I want to copy paste the textbox/label and change the label to "RM 01-01-02" and the texbox shoudl say Jenny.

Comment: Very creative solution to that problem.  I think the "mapping" aspect part of what you are trying to accomplish will prevent you from making use of a "standard" approach.  Maybe someone else will have a different idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your textbox will have a set of controls if the label is attached.

```
=DLookup("[OfficeOf]","tblLocationMSTR","[LocationCode]='" & Me.TextBox1.Controls(0).Caption & "'")
```

You will have to determine the name of the textbox on your form. I used **TextBox1** as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the form's OnLoad property to `[Event Procedure]` then add the following code behind the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim Ctl As Control

    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        If Ctl.Tag = "some_text_used_as_a_flag" Then
            Ctl.ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[OfficeOf]"",""tblLocationMSTR"",""[LocationCode]=""" & Ctl.Controls(0).Caption & """)"
        End If
    Next Ctl
End Sub
```

I assumed that you'll want a way to specify which label/textbox combos should be dynamically updated.  You can do that by setting the Tag property of each textbox to some specific text that you can check when looping through the controls.

Comment: Isn't the label of every control the first item in the controls collection, so it would be Me!MyControl.Controls(0)? I guess in an option group if you deleted the original label it might end up not being the first item in the collection, but I've always used Controls(0) to get at the labels.

Comment: I'm using `Controls(0)` in my code.  Which part of my code are you talking about?

Comment: I misinterpreted the code. I thought you were walking the controls collection to figure out which was a label. Having thought about this for a few days, I'm not entirely sure I feel comfortable relying on the label being the first item in the collection (even though I've got plenty of code that makes exactly that assumption). I can't think of a control other than an option group for which it would matter, though.